# Enable HTML select when radio button is checked or vice-versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something. I have the following code:

```
<form>
<input type='radio' name='radio_flavour' checked/>Unique flavour<br/><input class='double-flavoured' type='radio' name='radio_flavour'/>Double flavoured<br/>
<select>
<option>Select the second flavour...</option>";
foreach($connection->query($sql3) as $flavour)
{
    echo "<option value='{$flavour['flavour_id']}'>{$flavour['flavour_name']}</option>";
}
echo "
    </select>
</form>
```

What I need is when the second radio button `radio_flavour` with the class `double-flavoured` is selected, the HTML select under it will be enabled and vice-versa. I'm trying with this jQuery code:

```
$('.double-flavoured').change(function()
{
    var setE =  $(this).is(':checked') ? true : false;
    $(this).nextAll('select').first().attr('disabled', setE);
});
```

But this don't work!
How to do this with jQuery? Thanks!

Comment: You should use `value` to distinguish the different choices in a radio button group.

Comment: Have you considered generating a minimal example using jsfiddle?

Comment: Where's your javascript?

Comment: @romuleald I forgot it, sorry. I've updated the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code only runs when you click on the second button, not when you click on the first, since it doesn't have the `double-flavoured` class. You need to attach the handler to all the buttons in the group, and then test whether the one being selected has the class.

```js
$(":radio[name=radio_flavour]").click(function() {
  $(this).nextAll('select').attr('disabled', !$(this).hasClass("double-flavoured"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type='radio' name='radio_flavour' checked/>Unique flavour
  <br/>
  <input class='double-flavoured' type='radio' name='radio_flavour' />Double flavoured
  <br/>
  <select disabled>
    <option>Select the second flavour...</option>";

    <option value="1">Flavour 1</option>
    <option value="2">Flavour 2</option>
    <option value="3">Flavour 3</option>

  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Warn about using is possibly dangerous if the HTML come to change

Comment: @romuleald I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: Thank you, Barmar! Worked like a charm! I think this will help a lot of people. A great hug! :)